# How can I print list index in one line and the list elements in the next line in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

For example

```
l=[10,11,12,13,14]
```

I want the output as

```
0  1  2  3  4

10 11 12 13 14
```

The condition is that loop can only be used once

Comment: Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can simply use `enumerate` like this:

```
l = [10,11,12,13,14]
for x,y in enumerate(l):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Output:

```
0
10
1
11
2
12
3
13
4
14
```

If u want the output as a `list`, then use this code:

```
l=[10,11,12,13,14]

x_lst = []
y_lst = []

for x,y in enumerate(l):
    x_lst.append(x)
    y_lst.append(y)

print(x_lst)
print(y_lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

If u want them as a `string` separated by a space (as mentioned in the ques), then just add these lines to the above mentioned code (the 2nd code, not the first one):

```
x_lst = [str(x_lst[x]) for x in range(len(x_lst))]
y_lst = [str(y_lst[x]) for x in range(len(y_lst))]
print(' '.join(x_lst))
print(' '.join(y_lst))
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
10 11 12 13 14
```

Hope that this helps!