# I have a list like this x= [['a','b','c','d']] and I want to print all the elements in it like a b c d How do I do it?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list like this

```
x = [['a','b','c','d']]
```

and I want to print all the elements in it like

```
a 
b
c
d
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print list index in one line and the list elements in the next line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291066/how-can-i-print-list-index-in-one-line-and-the-list-elements-in-the-next-line-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to print list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items)

Comment: `for item in x[0]: print(item)`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [['a','b','c','d']]
print('\n'.join(map(str, x[0])))
```

result will be

```
a
b
c
d
```